# SSL validation failed for https://s3.zoneame.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_ VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, aws-cli

When I run the command `aws s3 ls` I'm getting this error:

```
SSL validation failed for https://s3.zonename.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_
VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
```

It work's fine with `--no-verify-ssl`

How can I make it work with ssl verficication?

```
aws s3 ls --debug
```

log below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connect
ionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
self._prepare_proxy(conn)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connect
ionpool.py", line 805, in _prepare_proxy
conn.connect()
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connect
ion.py", line 344, in connect
ssl_context=context)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ss
l_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
File "ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
File "ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
File "ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c
:749)
```

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall? This isn't necessarily indicative of an issue with AWS...

Comment: yes and we are using proxy for it.

Comment: That's probably your issue; loop in your network folks. I've seen this happen with network policies such as deep packet inspection frequently.

Comment: okay, if we use --no-verify-ssl to copy the data, will be the data on-flight secured and port used to transfer is 443 ?

Comment: You want certificate validation for proper security to prevent invalid certificates or man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is not using proxy per se (AWS CLI allows this by setting e.g. [HTTPS_PROXY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-proxy.html) environment variable) but the AWS CLI client not trusting proxy's certificate. Proxy's certificate might be self-signed, with your company set as CA (Certification Authority). AWS CLI client cannot find your company's CA root certificate in the local system's CA registry so it can't verify proxy's certificate and issues the `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` error.

To fix this we can pass company's root certificate (e.g. `company-root-ca.pem`) to AWS CLI client via [--ca-bundle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/credref/latest/refdocs/setting-global-ca_bundle.html) command parameter (or via `AWS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable or config file):

```
$ export HTTPS_PROXY=<host>:<port>
$ aws s3 ls --ca-bundle /path/to/company-root-ca.pem
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me. We use netskope which has its own certificates. I found a generic internal article with their paths, so maybe other corporate users have similar? I was trying to push a Docker container to AWS ECR but first needed to login in powershell: aws ecr get-login-password --region my-region --ca-bundle 'C:/somepath/somecert.pem' | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin some-repo.dkr.ecr.my-region.amazonaws.com

Comment: how do I find the path to the `company-root-ca.pem` file?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ export AWS_CA_BUNDLE="C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\botocore/cacert.pem"
```

This will work !! Enjoy

Comment: Thanks. It works on Windows from Git Bush terminal (MINGW64) to connect with aws-saml (behind corporate firewall)

Answer (score 1):

Update proxy settings solve my problem in windows system.

Steps for window 10:

1. In the search bar located on the left-hand side of your taskbar, next to the Windows
2. From the search results listed, click on the one that matches what you're looking for like in our case "Proxy settings".
3. Click on Proxy (left side bottom)
4. Add *.aws.amazon.com;
   [image]

Now run AWS cli command in CMD

Comment: This worked for me. My necessary server exemption was: *.amazonaws.com;

Answer (score 0):

I was using the S3 docker tools and I encountered this same issue.

Adding `--network=host` to the docker command fixed it for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me