# use of --no-verify-ssl to copy the data through aws cli to s3. secured or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, aws-cli

will be the data on-flight secured and port used to transfer is 443 ?  If we copy with the below command

`aws --no-verify-ssl s3 cp filename s3://bucketname/`

Answer (score 14):

As was commented on your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54689099/1695906), you really need to involve your network personnel to identify the correct solution.

With `--no-verify-ssl`, the traffic should still be *encrypted* but it **is not** *secure*.

With this option, you are explicitly disabling the mechanism designed to prevent misuse or forgery of an SSL certificate, and doing so makes it impossible for aws-cli to determine with reasonable confidence that the peer system with which it is communicating is indeed Amazon S3, not an impostor server, and not a man-in-the-middle observer/attack/exploit.

A need (or perceived need) to disable this validation is a sign of a defect in the system that needs to be resolved, such as by adding your enterprise CA to your local system trust store (assuming that's the issue -- it's the only marginally legitimate explanation that comes to mind, and if that is the actual problem, then I would argue that your organization is manipulating TLS in an improper way).

This workaround should be avoided.